# Variable declaration inside a loop doesn't reset it's value

Tags: vb.net

I was always under the impression that declaring a variable in VB.NET automatically sets this variable to it's data type's default value (unlike C#).

So, after

- `Dim intValue As Integer` `intValue` is 0
- `Dim dateValue As Date` `dateValue` is 1/1/0001
- `Dim stringValue As String` `stringValue` is `Nothing`
- `Dim strValue As Point` `strValue` is (0; 0)

and so on.

But now I declard a variable inside a loop and was surprised that despite the recurring declaration the variable kept it's value. So,

```
For index As Integer = 1 To 10
    Dim test As Integer

    test += 1

    Console.WriteLine(test)
Next index
```

outputs the numbers from 1 to 10 and is not outputting ten times the number 1.

Can somebody please explain why? Is this an error or is it supposed to work like that?

Answer (score 5):

The documentation says:

> Visual Basic assigns the specified value to the variable every time it runs the `Dim` statement. If you do not specify an initial value, Visual Basic assigns the default initial value for the variable's data type **when it first enters the code that contains the `Dim` statement**.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/variables/how-to-create-a-new-variable

Comment: Please refrain posting link only answers. In general you haven't answered the OP question at all, you've deferred the answering to somewhere else.

Comment: @Codexer - No, that's not true. My answer stand alone without the link. I've included the relevant passage in the documentation directly in the answer and I've only linked for supporting corroboration.

Comment: That's quite a surprising behavior, in the context of a loop. :/

Answer (score -2):

I humbly suggest that you try this:

```
Dim yourVariable as Integer = 0
```

Or replace the zero with any null consistent value depending on your work environment.

Comment: But what good is it for to declare a variable only inside the block it is used in (the loop) when it outlives the block it is declared in? I'd rather declare the variable on procedure level then and reset it in the loop if I have to reset it anyway.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get what you were trying to do.

VB.NET will run the declaration only once, but if you attribute a value while you make the declaration, VB.NET will do the attribution at each iteration of the loop even though it's not re-declaring the variable.

That's why you get 1 to 10 and not just 1 every time. If you declare and attribute the variable at the same time, you'll get 1 at every iteration.